# docpad plugin-tagging Why lists all the tags?

Tags: tags, tagging, docpad

Why lists all the [tags](http://altyncev.ru/posts/2013/05/megafon_login)?

[I use](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev_test/blob/master/src/layouts/post.html.eco):

```
<div class="tags">
  <ul>
    <% for tag, item of @getTagCloud(): %>
        <li><a class="tag_item" href="<%= item.url %>" data-tag-count="<%= item.count %>" data-tag-weight="<%= item.weight %>"><%= item.tag %> (<%= item.count %>)</a></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to display a specific page tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="tags">
  <ul>
    <% for tag in @document.tags: %>
      <li><a class="tag_item" href="<%= @getTagUrl(tag) %>"><%= tag %></a></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```